# REST: Why does the response have a status of 200 but a statusCode of 406?

Tags: rest-api

I have a simple api on Salesforce that returns some basic User data when called. It works fine however I noticed that the http status and statusCode are different. Is there something specific I have to do to get the two to be the same?

I'm just passing in a session ID via the Headers and one parameter which is a unique ID.

Here is how I form the response:

```
// Check if the customer key is null/blank
    if (requestBody.customerKey == null || String.isBlank(requestBody.customerKey)) {
        response.header.success = FALSE;
        response.header.statusCode = 406;
        response.header.error = 'The customerKey is required!';
        return response;
    }
```

Example request: 
[https://**myOrg**.com/services/apexrest/retrieveUserDetails?customerKey=](https://__myOrg__.com/services/apexrest/retrieveUserDetails?customerKey=)

Thanks in advance

[image: Screenshot from Postman]

Comment: can you post request  as well

Comment: Hi Oleksandr, yes sure thing. I've updated the question. Thanks

Comment: Also can you add the apex code ? As I can see its the custom Apex service where you manually set the status code

Comment: Sure thing, I have just added the relevant section as the class is a 150 lines+

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It works fine however I noticed that the http status and statusCode are different.

You are looking at two different codes here.

1. 200 is the response code here (can be set by using `response.statusCode`), which signifies that your request was successful and was processed by the server and thus you are getting the successful response here.
2. 406, is on the response header (`response.header.statusCode`, I am not sure though how are you able to set it this way as I am not able to access the `header` attribute on `HttpResponse/RestResponse`) and that you are explicitly setting in your post method when you are creating the response

> Is there something specific I have to do to get the two to be the same?

It depends on what do you want to pass on `response.statusCode` vs. `response.header.statusCode`. Ideally you will want to keep the values same.

Comment: Jayant, once again thanks so much for the clarification. It's now working as expected. For the record I just had to add: "RestContext.response.statusCode = 406" 

All the best

Answer (score 0):

As I can see from your endpoint : https://myOrg.com/services/apexrest/retrieveUserDetails?customerKey=123456
You are sending customerKey as a URL param and not a request body.

In your Apex code, you are check the request body

```
requestBody.customerKey == null || String.isBlank(requestBody.customerKey)
```

whereas your customerKey exists in your URL.

To retrieve the customerKey from the URL use requestURI

```
String customerKey= String id = RestContext.request.params.get('customerKey');
```

If you dont want to change the apex code, then create a JSON/XML based on your apex class

```
{
"customerKey":12345
}
```